# Deploying throws "Refused to apply style because its MIME type ('text/html')"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, render.com

I'm trying to deploy my React app on render.com and get this error:

> "Refused to apply style from
> 'https://delivery-app-test.onrender.com/shopping-cart/static/css/main.7acaea2f.css'
> because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."

Support from render.com did not help me. I do not understand how I can fix it.
For style, I use style components and MUI.
My structure of index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../src/index.css" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <title>React App</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function (l) {
        if (l.search[1] === '/') {
          var decoded = l.search
            .slice(1)
            .split('&')
            .map(function (s) {
              return s.replace(/~and~/g, '&');
            })
            .join('?');
          window.history.replaceState(
            null,
            null,
            l.pathname.slice(0, -1) + decoded + l.hash
          );
        }
      })(window.location);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Indeed the `.css` files should be of MIME type [text/css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types), show the code behind your error?

Comment: @Aleksandar in local invironment all works good. This issue appear when l deploy on render.com.

Comment: `https://delivery-app-test.onrender.com/shopping-cart/static/css/main.7acaea2f.css` only appears to be getting a 404 Not Found response.

Comment: @CBroe I see it. But file main.7acaea2f.css exist.